# Parse On Buddy Use topic instead of bundleid

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, buddy.com

I have migrated everything over from the old Parse.com to Parse on Buddy.  However, I constantly get the following error in my logs, especially when trying to send push notifications:

```
2017-09-27T22:58:02.306Z - 2 minutes ago - bundleId is deprecated, use topic instead
```

What does this mean, and where do I change bundleId to topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi this is Brad from Parse on Buddy. Although the error message is benign and can be ignored, it was caused by outdated configuration on our servers. We have changed the configuration, so if you still are seeing this please contact us at support@buddy.com. Thanks!